# Question about energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

Tom, weighted 60kg,  set a world record of bunjee jumping, he jumped off at 223m height, and reached the lowest point when he's 50m above ground. If 30% of mechanical energy was lost when the cord was stretched, what was the elastic potential energy stored in the cord when he reached lowest point?

My work ::

70% initial GPE = final GPE + EPE

0.7 * 60 * 9.81 * 223 = 60 * 9.81 * 50 + EPE

EPE = 62450 J

But the answer turn out to be 72660 J, what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to solve as follows,

The mechanical energy followed by reaching from the top to the bottom point is given by :

GPE = 60×10×(223-50) { g is taken as 10 for simplicity }

Now the question says that 30% of this energy got wasted while the cords were being stretched, so 70% of GPE is the required answer.

The mistake you were doing was that you had taken the change in GPE for the complete 223 m, however the person does not reach the bottom point. Also 0.7 × 60 × 10 ×  173 =  72660 J.